# Keyring using variables that read service and username in windows credentials

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-keyring

So the issue is we have an openLDAP server for authentication of our NAS drives in the office. Every time a computer is restarted the user has to input their password again to access the drives. Simply running a batch script to log into their drives in the morning works but the big boss doesn't like that their passwords are just sitting in raw text in the file.

So I've been plugging away in python to try and get a simple program to retrieve their password from windows credentials and toss that into a NET USE in os.system:

```
os.system("net use X: \\\\x.x.x.x password /user:username@domain.com")
```

I can retrieve the user name from a file simply enough from a variable opening a file and reading from a line. The issue is the password.

```
test_a = open('passtest.cfg', 'r')
test_b = open('passtest2.cfg', 'r')
test2_a = test_a.readline()
test2_b = test_b.readline()
drivepass = keyring.get_password(test2_a, test2_b)
```

The issue seems to be that keyring doesn't like reading from variables for some reason or another. At least i can't seem to figure out why it doesn't. It works just fine if i use:

```
drivepass = keyring.get_password("x.x.x.x", "username@domain.com")
```

The REAL problem is we need it simple enough that we can just move it around from workstation to workstation and just change the username@domain.com in a file and run it. So in the end the end product looks something like

```
os.system("net use X: \\\\x.x.x.x\foldername" + drivepass + "/user:" + test2_b)
```

Comment: It seems I've solved my own problem.

    drivepass = keyring.get_password("x.x.x.x", test2_b)

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've accidentally solved my own problem.

Didn't work:

```
drivepass = keyring.get_password(test2_a, test2_b)
```

Works:

```
drivepass = keyring.get_password("x.x.x.x", test2_b)
```

So the service arg in keyring apparently needs to not be a variable. to be fair though it doesn't need to be anyways. Hopefully somewhere down this line this helps somebody else.